# the difference between these two sentences

Tags: grammar

what does these two sentences means and are them correct and same?

***1. It is to be something good.***

***2. It is something to be good.***

thanks

best wishes

Comment: Can you describe what meaning you are trying to get across? Both sentences sound strange to me and whatever you are trying to express is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is to be something good.

This is not something a native English speaker would likely say, that is it is not idiomatic, but it would mean that something (whatever "it" is) *is intended to become something that is good*. I would probably express this as "*It will be something good*".

> It is something to be good.

Again, this is not exactly idiomatic but I can't say it is incorrect either. Some people use "something" to mean *noteworthy* or *significant* (for example the exclamation "*Isn't that something!*"). This could be taken to mean that *to be good* (to display the quality of goodness) *is remarkable*.

For clarity though, I would not use either of these in everyday speech and I suspect that whatever it is you are trying to express is neither of these meanings.